# Sitecore IconCache images not displaying, paths are incorrect

Tags: icons, sitecore, sitecore8.1

I'm trying to set up a Sitecore 8.1 instance that I've taken over from another agency. I have the site running but none of the image files from the IconCache are displaying in Sitecore:

[image]

I inspected the missing images and found that their paths are incorrect- they all begin with "/~/icon/" rather than "/temp/IconCache"

[image]

In the production instance, the icon paths are correctly set to /temp/IconCache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a know issue about this missing icons.
See Sitecore.Support.100371.100542

https://github.com/sitecoresupport/Sitecore.Support.100371.100542/releases

Another thing you can try is run the Clean up databases from the Control Panel, core database, but likely you need the patch.

For further research:

The icons are stored on file system in .zip files below:

> \sitecore\shell\Themes\Standard\

For example this url

> /~/icon/Office/24x24/publishing_restrictions.png.aspx

go to the

> \sitecore\shell\Themes\Standard\Office.zip

Check if the icons are on file system. And check if the url works, if the icon url not work find out why. which error? use the original Sitecore config files and web.config file. and check if it works.

You need to have this in config

```
<customHandlers>
    <handler trigger="~/icon/" handler="sitecore_icon.ashx" />
```

And in the web.config

```
<handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_icon.ashx" type="Sitecore.Resources.IconRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" name="Sitecore.IconRequestHandler" />
```

After the icon is used it is stored in the

> \temp\IconCache

directory.

Comment: Tried those suggestions but the issue is still happening

Comment: Update the answer, What error do you have when you try to get a icon in your browser. is there any custom URL filtering, redirection in your solution?

Comment: That was it -- the previous developers apparently commented out the sitecore_icon.ashx handler in from the web.config. Thanks!